# how to append an element to a list without keeping track of the index?

Tags: r, list, append

I am looking for the [r](/questions/tagged/r) equivalent of this simple code in [python](/questions/tagged/python)

```
mylist = []
for this in that:
  df = 1
  mylist.append(df)
```

basically just creating an empty list, and then adding the objects created within the loop to it.

I only saw R solutions where one has to specify the index of the new element (say `mylist[[i]] <- df`), thus requiring to create an index `i` in the loop.

Is there any simpler way than that to just append after the last element.

Comment: compare of `append` and `c`  http://rfunction.com/archives/2087

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a function called `append`:

```
ans <- list()
for (i in 1992:1994){
n <- 1 #whatever the function is
ans <- append(ans, n)
}

  ans
## [[1]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 1
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 1
##
```

***Note:*** Using `apply` functions instead of a for loop is better (not necessarily faster) but it depends on the actual purpose of your loop.

***Answering OP's comment:*** About using `ggplot2` and saving plots to a list, something like this would be more efficient:

```
plotlist <- lapply(seq(2,4), function(i) {
            require(ggplot2)
            dat <- mtcars[mtcars$cyl == 2 * i,]
            ggplot() + geom_point(data = dat ,aes(x=cyl,y=mpg))
})
```

<s>Thanks to [@Wen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962474/how-to-append-an-element-to-a-list-without-keeping-track-of-the-index/45962721#comment78884250_45962474) for sharing [Comparison of `c()` and `append()` functions](http://rfunction.com/archives/2087):</s>

> Concatenation (c) is pretty fast, but append is even faster and therefor preferable when concatenating just two vectors.

Comment: incredible. didnt find it. is this going to work whatever `df `may be? it may not be a scalar, but a whole dataframe or a `ggplot` plot

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ Check the updates. And the first one works for scalar or not scalar ones.

Comment: @Masoud Wait a second. If you look at the R code of the `append()` function, it just executes:  `c(x, values)`. How can `append()` be faster than `c()`??? The `append()` approach should give identical results as the `c()` one...

Comment: @DamianoFantini I am not sure looking at the output of `functionBody()` is the right approach for comparing performance of the functions. You may want to use `microbenchmark::microbenchmark()` and compare them.

Comment: You are right. I compared the 3 methods proposed here. `append()` is indeed the slowest.

Comment: This approach fails when the object being appended to the empty list is itself a list, because it returns the object being appended rather than a list containing the object being appended.

Comment: @Patrick care to share a reproducible example? Although this solution is intended for the question asked above and introducing other conditions doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Actually, I am incorrect here. I did not realize that `append(list(...), list(...))` acts the merge the lists in all cases rather than the add the list object as an additional item in the initial list. In any case, the solution is to simply wrap the new object in an additional layer of `list()`.

Comment: Happy to retract it, but I am unable to unless it is edited.

Comment: @Patrick no worries, I don't mind. it's not a great answer anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
mylist <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
  n <- 1
  mylist[[(length(mylist) +1)]] <- n
}
```

This seems to me the faster solution.

```
x <- 1:1000

aa <- microbenchmark({xx <- list(); for(i in x) {xx <- append(xx, values = i)} }) 
bb <- microbenchmark({xx <- list(); for(i in x) {xx <- c(xx, i)} } )
cc <- microbenchmark({xx <- list(); for(i in x) {xx[(length(xx) + 1)] <- i} } )

sapply(list(aa, bb, cc), (function(i){ median(i[["time"]]) / 10e5 }))
#{append}=4.466634 #{c}=3.185096 #{this.one}=2.925718
```

Answer (score 4):

There is: `mylist <- c(mylist, df)` but that's usually not the recommended way in R. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, `lapply()` is often a better option.

Answer (score 3):

```
mylist <- list()
for (i in 1:100) {
     df <- 1
     mylist <- c(mylist, df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
first_list = list(a=0,b=1)
newlist = c(first_list,list(c=2,d=3))

print(newlist)
```

$a
[1] 0

$b
[1] 1

$c
[1] 2

$d
[1] 3

---

Here's an example:

```
glmnet_params = list(family="binomial", alpha = 1,
type.measure = "auc",nfolds = 3, thresh = 1e-4, maxit = 1e3)
```

Now:

```
glmnet_classifier = do.call("cv.glmnet",
    c(list(x = dtm_train, y = train$target), glmnet_params))
```