# cannot use ggsave after marrangeGrob

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I am using the following setup to create a list of [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) charts.

This works pretty well:

```
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

mycols <- c('year','displ')

mylist <- list()
for(item in mycols){

  p <- ggplot(mpg, aes_string(x = 'hwy', y = item)) +  
    geom_point()
  mylist[[(length(mylist) +1)]] <- p
}

ml = marrangeGrob(grob = mylist, nrow=2, ncol=1)
ggsave("P://multipage.pdf", ml, width =10, height = 5)
```

However, in the loop, replacing:

- `mylist[[(length(mylist) +1)]]` with
- `mylist <- append(mylist, p)` as discussed here [how to append an element to a list without keeping track of the index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45962474/how-to-append-an-element-to-a-list-without-keeping-track-of-the-index) will throw an error at the `ggsave` stage:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "wrapvp", value = list(x = 0.5, y =
>   0.5,  :    replacement has 17 rows, data has 234

What is the problem here? Individually, all the charts in the list look fine.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @MrFlick thanks. I am updating right now. I have found an interesting bug

Comment: yeah thats true. let me try with the usual toy example

Comment: @MrFlick wonderful edit dont you think? :)

Comment: argh wait a sec

Comment: @MrFlick good to go. sorry about that

Comment: `purr::map` you mean? How can I integrate that to the code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with `marrangeGrob` and has to do with how you are building your list. Compare the structure of the output of these methods

```
out1 <- list()
out1[[length(out1)+1]]<-list(a=1, b=2)
out1[[length(out1)+1]]<-list(a=2, b=2)
str(out1)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ a: num 1
#   ..$ b: num 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ a: num 2
#   ..$ b: num 2

out2 <- list()
out2 <- append(out2, list(a=1, b=2))
out2 <- append(out2, list(a=2, b=2))
str(out2)
# List of 4
#  $ a: num 1
#  $ b: num 2
#  $ a: num 2
#  $ b: num 2
```

Notice that they produce different structures. The `append()` adds the elements to the "root" list rather than nesting the list in the list. You can explicitly do that yourself with and extra `list()`

```
out3 <- list()
out3 <- append(out3, list(list(a=1, b=2)))
out3 <- append(out3, list(list(a=2, b=2)))
str(out3)
# List of 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ a: num 1
#   ..$ b: num 2
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ a: num 2
#   ..$ b: num 2
```

but messing with loops in R like this is rarely necessary. Better to use a built in iterator like `lapply()` or `Map()`. For example

```
mylist <- lapply(mycols, function(item) {
  ggplot(mpg, aes_string(x = 'hwy', y = item)) + 
    geom_point()
})
```

Comment: very clear and entertaining. thanks! a nasty example of nested vs unnested loops